# Block the notifications from a Chrome Extension on my website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have an issue with a Chrome Extension on my website (online store). Doesn't matter which extension exactly, there are plenty of them. These extensions shows the notification with lower prices on other stores.

And it happens after a user has clicked on the paid ad. The extension stealing the ad marketing budget and/or the potential buyers.

My research says thah there are no way to block it... am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you are correct. There is no way to prohibit extensions from running on your page. You can try to employ clever tricks to _break_ a specific extension, but it'll just be a cat&mouse game that all your customers may suffer from.

Comment: @Xan Thank you! Yes, I can prevent editing the DOM of my page by an extension via the MutationObserver(filter and then rollback the changes), but there are no way to block the extension itself or notifications from it. I just thought maybe I miss something.

Comment: You can, until the extension takes steps to neuter your protection. The point is: whatever security measures you take, they _can_ be circumvented as the extension is allowed to run arbitrary code before yours does. You can make someone's life difficult, but you will not win. I would say: just like with ad-blockers, respect the user's choice to have that extension. The majority of your audience won't have it.

Comment: @Xan It is about huge russian company Yandex with their own search, browser, ad network etc. Their audience in Russia is more than Google, so you can not abandon Yandex ad network.
They not only distribute the extension as is, but also secretly embedding its code in many other popular extensions(Crome/FF). Many users have no idea that they have this code.
As an online store: you buy from them ad slots, and they steal money and clients and show links to other stores on top of your site.